# geb withconfirm throwing No signature of method: geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator.getJs()?

Tags: grails, functional-testing, geb, grails-4

I have created a simple hello world app and here is the spec to test withconfirm block.

https://github.com/learningcscience/confirmgeb/blob/master/src/integration-test/groovy/booktest/BookSpec.groovy

It is throwing the error when i run the functional test.

```
No signature of method: geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator.getJs() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: getX(), getY(), getX(), getY(), getAt(groovy.lang.EmptyRange), getAt(groovy.lang.Range)
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator.getJs() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: getX(), getY(), getX(), getY(), getAt(groovy.lang.EmptyRange), getAt(groovy.lang.Range)
    at geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator.methodMissing(NonEmptyNavigator.groovy:558)
    at geb.content.PageContentSupport.methodMissing(PageContentSupport.groovy:35)
```

The line where the error is thrown is the withConfirm block. Why is it throwing this error? According to the docs

```
The first method, withConfirm() (and its ‘ok’ defaulted relative), is used to verify actions that will produce a confirm dialog. This method returns the confirmation message. The ok parameter controls whether the “OK” or “Cancel” button should be clicked.
```

and the example from the docs is

```
assert withConfirm(true) { $("input", name: "showConfirm").click() } == "Do you like Geb?"
```

http://www.gebish.org/manual/2.3/

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

If it is relevant i am using the following version chrome driver.

```
webdriverBinaries {
    chromedriver {
        version = '100.0.4896.20'
        architecture = 'X86'
    }
    geckodriver '0.24.0'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The missing method should point to the js-object (https://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#js-object).

You are using some outdated versions. After Update some dependencies to a consistent level in the build.gradle, the tests will run.

```
testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:3.141.59"
testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:3.141.59"
testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:3.141.59"
testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:3.141.59"
testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:3.141.59"
testCompile 'org.gebish:geb-core:4.1'
testCompile 'org.gebish:geb-spock:4.1'
```

Than you can add a assertion to your spec (BookSpec):

```
withConfirm(true) {
    $("#btn").click()
}
```

Btw. our grailsw is outdated: https://grails.org/blog/2021-06-10-grails-wrapper-update.html

Comment: thank you very much. that did it.  should i keep testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb" or should i replace it with testCompile group: 'org.gebish', name: 'geb-core', version: '4.1' ? Thanks

Comment: could you please help me with this issue as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71891517/how-to-run-geb-functional-test-in-https

Comment: The grails.plugins:geb ist for the link to the grails project on startup. geb-core is for the selenium-browser testing. There is also an dependency to testCompile 'org.gebish:geb-spock:4.1' update.